# SQL Finding most spoken language in a country

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the most spoken language in a country based on percentage. I am joining 2 tables:

```
Country(NAME,CODE)
CountryLanguage(Percentage, CountryCode, Language)
```

Joining those 2 gives me

```
Aruba           Dutch       5.3
Aruba           English     9.5
Aruba           Papiamento  76.7
Aruba           Spanish     7.4
Afghanistan     Balochi     0.9
Afghanistan     Dari        32.1
Afghanistan     Pashto      52.4
Afghanistan     Turkmenian  1.9
Afghanistan     Uzbek       8.8
```

I tried to get the most spoken language by saying

```
SELECT co.Name, cl.language, max(cl.Percentage)
from Country co, CountryLanguage cl
where co.Code = cl.CountryCode
group by co.Name
```

This gives me the right percentage but wrong language, where did I go wrong?

```
Afghanistan  Balochi    52.4
Aruba        Dutch      76.7
```

Comment: group by co.name,cl.language  will get you desired result

Comment: Side note use proper INNER JOIN syntax instead off the old comma JOIN syntax.

Comment: @BHouse That gives me more than one output for each country tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please join with `inner join...on`.

Your query won't work as it will get max(percentage) but display any of `language` for given `country`.

If I understood your schema properly, then following query should work as expected:

```
SELECT co.Name, cl.language, cl.Percentage as percentage
from Country co 
inner join CountryLanguage cl
on co.Code = cl.CountryCode
where (cl.CountryCode,cl.Percentage) in (select CountryCode,max(Percentage)
                                         from CountryLanguage
                                         group by CountryCode)
group by co.Name
```

Comment: I mean it works, mind explaining how the where clause works?

Comment: `where` clause will select the rows from joined table that have pair of `(CountryCode,max(Percentage))` In your query, you were only selecting `max(Percentage)` , which will show the any arbitarily `language` instead of the one with `max(Percentage)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowing functions to get this answer:

`RANK` with a `PARTITION` will do the trick

```
With RecordedPercentages AS
(
              Select 'Aruba' Country, 'Dutch' LanguageName, Cast (5.3 as float) Percentage
    Union All Select 'Aruba', 'English', 9.5
    Union All Select 'Aruba', 'Papiamento', 76.7
    Union All Select 'Aruba', 'Spanish', 7.4
    Union All Select 'Afghanistan', 'Balochi', 0.9
    Union All Select 'Afghanistan', 'Dari', 32.1
    Union All Select 'Afghanistan', 'Pashto', 52.4
    Union All Select 'Afghanistan', 'Turkmenian', 1.9
    Union All Select 'Afghanistan', 'Uzbek', 8.8
),
MyRanking As
(
    Select 
    Country, LanguageName, Percentage, 
    Rank() Over (Partition by Country Order by Percentage Desc) Ranking
    From RecordedPercentages
)
Select *
From MyRanking
Where Ranking = 1
```

Comment: You're a little ahead of where most MySQL users are presently at.

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding group by both columns

```
SELECT co.Name, cl.language, max(cl.Percentage)
from Country co, CountryLanguage cl
where co.Code = cl.CountryCode
group by co.Name,cl.language
```

Comment: See if I do that it gives me more than one output for each country